# understanding materials (I guess)

Tags: materials

I have a mystery.
Rendering my model with a Hemi light (default setting) and a spot (default with slight Light Color change). Both placed above model.

When I render and see the shading calculation(?) I get (correct) shadows inside nostrils.
[image: shading while rendering image - notstrils have internal shade]
When final image is done - I suddenly have **light inside nostrils??** And I just can't seem to figure out what is doing this? I have SSS on skin but nostrils-area (with marked seem around) does not (anymore... as I believed SSS to be the reason earlier).
[image: light inside nostrils]
Any tips on what this could be caused by?

Rookie stuff, I'm sure, but I guess I AM a rookie. Trying ty improve

Comment: Please upload your file to make it easier to investigate.

Comment: Looks like you're using Blender Internal, you should specify it in the question. In Internal, hemi lights don't project shadows, so the inside of the nostrils aren't occluded by the head. You can fake an hemi light which project shadow, by adding a dome of spots around your scene.

Comment: @thibsert do you mean the render engine (instead of using 'cycles' or 'game')? If so I haven't really begun understanding what does what (and what's good for what)

Comment: @Jackdaw - where would I upload it to?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @morganF Yes that's what i mean (Instead of "Blender Internal" i should have said "Blender Render"). The engine you're using appears in the Info tab, just between the Scene selector and the Blender icon.